# Unit tests for handled exceptions

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This is what I have in code:

```
function myMethod()
{
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        if (noMatch)
        {
            //
            SendEmailAndStopProcessing();
            continue;
        }
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have a csv file which has multiple lines and I process them if there is a match with a db value.

I want to create a unit test that confirms that if noMatch is found, then the email will be sent and doSomething wont be executed. I don't have an exception here because there is no need of that, it is handled by sending email (those were the business rules). However I need to create a unit test to confirm that this case is handled. How should I handle that? If there was an exception I would have added the attribute for expected exception in my test method, but since there is not, I am stuck.

Comment: "...and `doSomething` won't be executed"? This won't ever happen. You are either missing a `return` or an `else` statement.

Comment: what is `noMatch`?  how is it determined?  You can do this pretty simply as long as your "files" can be manipulated in a manner, and your `SendEmailAndStopProcessing` and `doSomething` are either: `virtual`, or perhaps better, a separate injectable service that can be mocked and verified based on your mocking of the result of `noMatch`.  Also what @RenéVogt said :D

Comment: @RenéVogt I missed a continue statement, sorry. I edited the code.

Comment: @Kritner I parse the lines from the file and compare them with some values in db, they should be the same. If that is not the case, i stop processing the files and send email to the admin to notify him to change the file.

Comment: Do you want to stop processing all the files, or just the current file? At the moment you are just stopping the current file.

Comment: @Lee Yes, that is what I want to happen, stop the processing of the current file only.

Comment: Hum... its hard to explain why, but your idea of unit testing is somewhat not exactly right, I think. You should not unit test UI components such as access to file and email libraries, they should be covered by some kind of higher tier test (integration, end-to-end, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever functionality is sending the email within SendEmailAndStopProcessing() should be pulled out into an interface (IEmailSender or something), allowing you to inject that interface in through the constructor of your class.

Once you have this, you can use Moq or some other mocking framework, to replace the IEmailSender implementation with a stub which won't actually send an email. With these you can usually do assertions on how many times a method was called, if at all, so if you were using Moq (for example), you could do.

emailMock.Verify(x => x.SendEmail(), Times.Once)

Which would fail if your SendEmail wasn't called. You could do something similar for your OrSomething method, also.

The key is isolating components into interfaces, so that they can be swapped out at will, using the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 0):

As Kritner has said: create a mock of `SendEmailAndStopProcessing` and count how often it has been called. This of course assumes that `SendEmailAndStopProcessing` can be mocked (method is accessible from test class and can be overridden).

For example using [Moq](http://www.developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/):

```
using Moq;

// ARRANGE
var serviceMock = new Mock<MyService>();
serviceMock.Setup(s => s.SendEmailAndStopProcessing()).Verifiable();
// ACT: call myMethod()
// ASSERT
const int expectedNumberOfCalls = 1;
serviceMock.Verify(x => x.SendEmailAndStopProcessing(), Times.Exactly(expectedNumberOfCalls));
```